# Что пишут на java?

Tags: java

Я никак не понимаю, что я буду делать на работе, выучив джаву. Назовите, пожалуйста, примеры программ, к-е на ней чаще пишутся. Что я могу написать, чтобы показать работодателю? 
Я начала учить ее из интереса, интерес не пропадает, и вот подумалось мне: надо  как нибудь использовать накопленные знания,и тут я поняла, что понятия не имею что, кого, чего...
написание игр не интересует.

Comment: В основном пишут игры для android по моему подходит и для ios. Но и чаще пишут плагины разные

Comment: а забыла уточнить: desktop. игры не хочу.

Comment: Да конечно можно и desktop это же уникальный язык но щас для desktop лучше c# но в будущем может java станет лидером это незнаю. Но точно знаю java крутой язык можно и desktop application написать. Немного прямых рук и трудолюбия

Comment: Вопрос явно оффтопик, т.к. слишком общий. Ну а вообще можно выделить 2,5 направления для JAVA. 1 - серверная часть, в ней java закрепилась как лидер; 2 - android разработка, почти лидер; 2,5 - различные GUI - приложения. Но Java для десктоп приложений не очень популярна, за иключением IDE (Intellij Idea, Eclipse и производных от них)

Comment: + веб приложения, сервисы

Answer (score 2):

Что можно делать на Java? То же, что и на C, C++, Python, PHP, Ruby... Все, что придет в голову:

- Игры: Minecraft (но в gamedev в основном C#/C++ используется)
- Приложения на Андроид: Java является основным языком для написания программ на андроид
- Приложения: используюя JavaFX, или Swing, или какую-либо другую библиотеку, можно с легкостью создавать приложения для компьютера. Допустим, компилятор **Eclipse** написан на C и Java. **Gmail** написан на Java. **Nasa World Wind** написан на C# и Java.

Много примеров. Хороший и полезный язык.

Далее взято из этого [источника](http://proglang.su/java/introduction-to-programming)

Почему Java?

> Преимущества Java как языка программирования Объектно-ориентированный:
>   в Java все является объектом. Дополнение может быть легко расширено,
>   так как он основан на объектной модели.
>
> **Платформонезависимый:** в отличие от многих других языков, включая C и
>   C++, Java, когда был создан, он не компилировался в платформе
>   конкретной машины, а в независимом от платформы байт-коде. Этот байт
>   код распространяется через интернет и интерпретируется в Java Virtual
>   Machine (JVM), на которой он в настоящее время работает.
>
> **Простой**: процессы изучения и введение в язык программирования Java
>   остаются простыми. Если Вы понимаете основные концепции
>   объектно-ориентированного программирования, то он будет прост для Вас
>   в освоении.
>
> **Безопасным:** методы проверки подлинности основаны на шифровании с
>   открытым ключом.
>
> **Архитектурно-нейтральным:** компилятор генерирует
>   архитектурно-нейтральные объекты формата файла, что делает
>   скомпилированный код исполняемым на многих процессорах, с наличием
>   системе Java Runtime.
>
> **Портативный:** архитектурно-нейтральный и не имеющий зависимости от
>   реализации аспектов спецификаций — все это делает Java портативным.
>   Компилятор в Java написан на ANSI C с чистой переносимостью, который
>   является подмножеством POSIX.
>
> **Прочный:** выполняет усилия, чтобы устранить ошибки в различных
>   ситуациях, делая упор в основном на время компиляции, проверку ошибок
>   и проверку во время выполнения.
>
> **Многопоточный:** функции многопоточности, можно писать программы,
>   которые могут выполнять множество задач одновременно. Введение в язык
>   Java этой конструктивной особенности позволяет разработчикам создавать
>   отлаженные интерактивные приложения.
>
> **Интерпретированный:** Java байт-код переводится на лету в машинные
>   инструкции и нигде не сохраняется. Делая процесс более быстрым и
>   аналитическим, поскольку связывание происходит как дополнительное с
>   небольшим весом процесса.
>
> **Высокопроизводительный:** введение Just-In-Time компилятора, позволило
>   получить высокую производительность.
>
> **Распространенный:** предназначен для распределенной среды интернета.
>
> **Динамический:** программирование на Java считается более динамичным, чем
>   на C или C++, так как он предназначен для адаптации к меняющимся
>   условиям. Программы могут выполнять обширное количество во время
>   обработки информации, которая может быть использована для проверки и
>   разрешения доступа к объектам на время выполнения.

Answer (score 1):

На `Java` пишут практически всё что угодно.

Например среды разработки (`IDE`) от `JetBrains` написаны на `Java` - это пример десктоп программ.

Также можно писать сервера. Для этого можно использовать фреймворк `Spring`.

И `Android` - на нём `Java` - один из официальных языков разработки нативных приложений. Второй - `Kotlin`, коий пишет та же `JetBrains` и который полностью совместим с `Java` и является её, грубо говоря, улучшенной версией.